# Authenticate into local App Engine server via Paw app for Mac

Tags: google-app-engine, localhost, paw-app

I'm running App Engine's local [`dev_appserver.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) and trying to authenticate using the [Paw app for Mac](https://paw.cloud/).

Here Paw correctly renders the login page:

[image: Paw rendering the local dev server login page]

However, every time I sign in, it asks me if I'd like to open the subsequent page in Chrome.

[image: Paw responding with "This web page wants to open the following link"]

I would like Paw to store the login credentials but have no idea how to tell it to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a hacky way around this by manually copying cookie values from Google Chrome. Here's how I did that:

1. Sign in to local app via Chrome
2. Open **Developer Tools**
3. Under **Storage**, expand **Cookies** and click on `http://localhost:8080`
4. Find the cookie named `dev_appserver_login`

[image: Cookies in the Developer Tools Application tab]

Next, it's as simple as copying over each value into Paw's `Cookie Sessions` window.

1. Open the **Cookie Sessions** window
2. Copy over the `Name`, `Value`, `Domain`, and `Path` into a row in the cookies list

[image: Paw session cookies list]

Going back to Paw and executing a request that requires auth, everything works:

[image: Paw after]